# Mocking Parent or Child of `System.Windows.FrameworkElement`

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have the following method in a class called `MouseWheelListenerViewManager`:

```
protected static void PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Handled)
        {
            e.Handled = true;

            var eventArg = new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta);
            eventArg.RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseWheelEvent;
            eventArg.Source = sender;

            UIElement ancestor = ((FrameworkElement)sender).Parent as UIElement;
            while (ancestor != null)
            {
                ancestor.RaiseEvent(eventArg);
                ancestor = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(ancestor) as UIElement;
            }
        }
}
```

I would like to test that the `.Parent` of `sender` is called(and all other ancestors).

I wrote this unit test:

```
[Test]
public void PreviewMouseWheel_is_sent_to_ancestors()
  {
        TestableMouseWheelViewManager mouseWheelListenerViewManager = new TestableMouseWheelViewManager();
        BorderedCanvas canvas = mouseWheelListenerViewManager.CreateView(new ThemedReactContext(new ReactContext()));
        mouseWheelListenerViewManager.AddListeners(canvas);
        MouseDevice mouseDev = InputManager.Current.PrimaryMouseDevice;
        Mock<MouseWheelEventArgs> me = new Mock<MouseWheelEventArgs>(mouseDev, 0, 0);
        me.Object.RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseWheelEvent;

        ///start of most relevant code

        Mock<FrameworkElement> sender = new Mock<FrameworkElement>();
        Mock<StackPanel> parent = new Mock<StackPanel>();
        Mock<StackPanel> grandParent = new Mock<StackPanel>();
        parent.Object.Children.Add(sender.Object);
        grandParent.Object.Children.Add(parent.Object);
        TestableMouseWheelViewManager.PreviewMouseWheel(sender, me.Object);

        ///end of most relevant code

        parent.Verify(mock => mock.RaiseEvent(It.IsAny<RoutedEventArgs>()), Times.Once());
        grandParent.Verify(mock => mock.RaiseEvent(It.IsAny<RoutedEventArgs>()), Times.Once());
}
```

However, the test code throws this exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

On this line:

```
parent.Object.Children.Add(sender.Object);
```

Instead of setting the `Children`, I tried setting the `Parent` like this:

```
sender.Parent = parent;
```

However, that is not possible because the `Parent` of `FrameworkElement` is read-only.

So how can I mock a `FrameworkElement` inheritance chain?

Comment: I see no need for mocking the element here. Just create an instance and populate the necessary members to exercise the test

Comment: I have close to no experience with .NET. Would you have any suggestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

#### How you can test your code

Moq will only bring you pain when trying to mock concrete classes, as you are trying to do here (`FrameworkElement`), as you have discovered.

Instead, you should consider writing your test with instances of the concrete `FrameworkElement` objects. Thankfully, instantiating a `FrameworkElement` does not require a boatload of dependencies.

In order to verify the `FrameworkElement.RaiseEvent()` method was called, you may subscribe to each of the `FrameworkElement.MouseWheel` events with a handler that will flag that it had been called.

```
FrameworkElement sender = new FrameworkElement();
FrameworkElement parent = new FrameworkElement();
FrameworkElement grandParent = new FrameworkElement();

parent.Children.Add(sender);
grandParent.Children.Add(parent);

Dictionary<FrameworkElement, bool> callFlags = { 
    {sender, False},
    {parent, False},
    {grandParent, False} 
};
var handler = (sndr, e) => { callFlags[(sndr as FrameworkElement)] = True };

sender.MouseWheel += handler;
parent.MouseWheel += handler;
grandParent.MouseWheel += handler;

/* run tests */

// assert all call flags have been set to true
Assert.IsTrue(callFlags.All(cf => cf), "A MouseWheel event in the hierarchy was not raised");
```

(I am unable to test this code at the moment, so hopefully it's correct enough to give an idea)

#### Why you got the error in your question (bonus)

Again, you probably will not be able to use Moq with concrete `FrameworkElement` objects. I will simply explain why you got the error your reported.

In Moq, `new Mock<T>(MockBehavior)` takes a `MockBehavior` argument. [This a really good source on what this does](http://codebetter.com/aaronjensen/2008/03/26/moq-s-mockbehavior/). That argument is *optional*.

The gist is that since you call the default constructor for `Mock<T>`, the behavior that gets passed is `MockBehavior.Default`. This means that, in absence of specific `setup()`, when you call the shadowed members of `Mock<T>.Object`, Moq will instantiate a default value for their respective types, e.g. if you call an `int` member, Moq returns `0`, a `bool` member returns `False` and a complex type member returns `null`.

Now to your code (excerpt):

```
Mock<FrameworkElement> sender = new Mock<FrameworkElement>();
Mock<StackPanel> parent = new Mock<StackPanel>();
parent.Object.Children.Add(sender.Object);
```

Because `parent` was instantiated with `MockBehavior.Default`, and since you have never called `parent.Setup(p => p.Children).Returns(...)`, you get:

```
parent.Object.Children == null
// True
```

Please note that in Moq, when you mock a type, you will need to evaluate the merits of the different `MockBehavior` values, and either call `Setup()` or leave the behavior to decide for each members that will get called in your test method.

Comment: So in my case, what can I do? I tried something like this: `sender.Setup(s => s.Parent).Returns(parent.Object);` but it didn't work `Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: s => s.Parent`

Comment: That is Moq’s limitation: it can only mock abstract or virtual members. The error message here is correct in what is happening.

Comment: I overlooked that you’d run into this issue (Moq is a few months behind me now...). I’ll edit the answer.

Comment: Hopefully, it is more helpful to you now